# pyautogui keep shift pressed

Tags: python, pyautogui

```py
import pyautogui as pag

while True:
    pag.press('shift')
    pag.click(975, 450, 1, 1, 'right')
    pag.click(808, 600, 1, 1, 'right')
    pag.click(840, 600, 1, 1, 'right')
    pag.click(880, 600, 1, 1, 'right')
    pag.click(920, 600, 1, 1, 'right')
    pag.click(955, 600, 1, 1, 'right')
    pag.click(992, 600, 1, 1, 'right')
```

How can I do to shift maintain pressed because it stops to be pressed

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-press-keydown-and-keyup-functions), you should use the `keyDown()` method to achieve what you are asking, so something like this should do the trick:

```
import pyautogui as pag

while True:
    pag.keyDown('shift')
    pag.click(975, 450, 1, 1, 'right')
    pag.click(808, 600, 1, 1, 'right')
    pag.click(840, 600, 1, 1, 'right')
    pag.click(880, 600, 1, 1, 'right')
    pag.click(920, 600, 1, 1, 'right')
    pag.click(955, 600, 1, 1, 'right')
    pag.click(992, 600, 1, 1, 'right')
```

Don't forget to do a `keyUp('shift')` once you are done with your task.